# Examples for thread divergence actions and external actions in the Java Memory Model

Tags: java, multithreading, java-native-interface, native, java-memory-model

I'm currently learning about the Java Memory Model and I came about the different kinds of [Actions](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.4.2).

There are two of them which I don't fully understand:

- *External Actions* and
- *Thread divergence actions*

Please explain those two action types and give examples for them and for their special properties regarding **compiler-reordering** and **happens-before relation**. Oh, and are native calls also external actions?

I think they wouldn't define thread divergence actions if there was nothing special about them. So what makes them special so that they need to be defined as a special kind of action?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The existing answer already correctly defines what these actions are.

As for the reordering: look at the following example of a *thread-divergence* action:

```
class ThreadDivergence { 

  int foo = 0; 

  void thread1() { 
    while (true); // thread-divergence action
    foo = 42; 
  } 

  void thread2() { 
    assert foo == 0; 
  } 
}
```

You would expect this assertion to never fail. Without thread-divergence actions, this could not be guaranteed because the unreachable definition of setting `foo = 42` could be reordered to be executed first. This is forbidden by the JMM.

Similarly, *external actions* are added to avoid surprising outcomes:

```
class Externalization { 

  int foo = 0; 

  void method() { 
    jni(); // external action
    foo = 42; 
  } 

  native void jni(); /* { 
    assert foo == 0; 
  } */ 
}
```

Assuming that the JNI method was implemented to run the same assertion, you would not expect this to fail. The JIT compiler cannot determine the outcome of anything *external* such that the JMM forbidds such reorderings, too.

Comment: Any JVM communicates with "external world" via native methods which are "External Actions". Also external actions have one additional parameter: either exception thrown by that action or the result that is returned by the native method.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, External Action is something visible outside of the Java VM process, such as displaying a window, writing to a file or connectiong to a socket.

Thread Divergence Action must be entering an infinite `while(true)` loop.

Comment: And what are their special properties regarding *compiler-reordering*? Are all native methods external actions?

Comment: or asking the other way, is there a way how a non native method can be external?

Comment: The only thing that may be non-native and external that occurrs to me is UNSAFE. But I am not sure if it's non-native...

Comment: I think they wouldn't declare divergence actions if there was nothing special about them. So what makes them special?

Comment: OK, I am just guessing now, but I think the special part about divergence actions is that once a thread has one, it no longer matters. It's in an infinite loop and will never emerge.